# C# parsing MTOM response from web-service

Tags: c#, xml, soap, веб-служба

Веб-сервис поставщика возвращает ответ вида (MTOM):

```
--uuid:5251c679-2917-1111-bbbf-44a5963ee0ac
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
/* здесь данные xml */
</soap:Envelope>
--uuid:5251c679-2917-1111-bbbf-44a5963ee0ac
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <fb67ac70-5a7e-47f5-b805-7ec4b14e1857-524@urn://XXX>

/* здесь бинарные данные */
--uuid:5251c679-2917-1111-bbbf-44a5963ee0ac--
```

Как распарсить ответ и вытащить xml?

В HTTP-заголовок вставляю следующие параметры:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RequestURI);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/xop+xml;charset=\"utf-8\";type=\"text/xml\"";            
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Timeout = 30000;
```

Comment: Можно с помощью WCF [читать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869076/5045688) MTOM.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov При xmlReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(ResponseStream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max); возникает ошибка  Чтение потока "System.Net.ConnectStream" не поддерживается

Comment: Что это вообще за сервис? Он предоставляет WSDL или другое подобное описание своих сервисов? Чтоб сгенерировать по нему код клиента.

Comment: Гм. Можно попробовать сперва прочитать контент в `MemoryStream`, а уже его подать `MtomReader`у.